# What does "unwarranted conclusion" mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology, collocation

What does "unwarranted conclusion" mean in a context that especially is related to a scientific survey?

Apparently it means  that drawing a conclusion without taking into account whole variables or factors that impact the conclusion. However, I could not find a source explaining the term well.

Comment: It just means drawing a conclusion that isn't supported by the facts.  It could be making a leap not based at all on the evidence, or basing it on evidence that could lead to many different, competing conclusions, not just the one you claim.  Your explanation would be another example.

Comment: @fixer1234  Thank you. You mean like " to jump to conclusions"

Comment: They're similar.  "Jump to conclusions" tends to imply laziness; accepting a conclusion without rigorous analysis.  An "unwarranted conclusion" could result from flawed analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminology may be common in science, but isn't exactly jargon. *Unwarranted* here simply means not *warranted*, in the sense of justified (by good logic/reason/rationale).

The most relevant definition in the Oxford Dictionary of English for the verb *warrant* is the following, although the sense is obviously not quite a "course of action".

> 1. justify or necessitate (a course of action): the employees feel that industrial action is warranted.

Likewise, the [relevant entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/225840?rskey=Zkf49B&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid) in the Oxford English Dictionary (OED, which is distinct, despite the very similar name) is:

> 6. a. To attest the truth or authenticity of; to authenticate.

There is also an 'obsolete' sense which is perhaps most suggestive of the sense in which it is used in "unwarranted conclusion".

> 11. †d. To justify by appeal to authority or evidence, to find warrant for. Obsolete.

Does that help clarify?

Comment: Do you think "unwarrented generalization" is the same? I found a website explaning it. Can I use the examples for "unwarranted conclusion" as well?        http://www.txstate.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/Unwarranted-Generalization.html

Comment: A generalisation may be a type of conclusion. (I'd say it's an abductive/inductive one, rather than a deductive one.) But it's certainly not the only one. That's the logician in me speaking, at least. And you're quite welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Unwarranted is the opposite of warranted.

Something is 'unwarranted' if it is;

- 'not justified'
- 'not authorised', or
- 'not reasonable'

If the conclusions of a scientific (fact or evidence based) survey are thought to be 'unwarranted', then something has gone wrong.

The surveyor has drawn conclusions that the survey evidence does not support.  They are making it up...  The conclusion is 'fiction'.  It is 'bad science'...